# Why can't Muslims eat food offered by non-Muslims?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food

A Muslim friend of mine turned down chocolates that I offered.

He told me that his parents told him not to accept food offered by non-Muslims, as it would be *haram*. Why is this so?

Note: The chocolate does not contain any ingredients that would be considered *haram*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Islam. See also [Is it permissible for a Muslim to eat something offered by a non-Muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/is-it-permissible-for-a-muslim-to-eat-something-which-is-offered-by-a-non-muslim?rq=1)

Comment: Muslims *can* eat food offered by non-Muslims, with some exceptions. His parents might have told him to avoid it as the food *could* be haram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Muslim and I have many **non-muslim friends** in my college and also during my school life. During the lunch break, we **share** our food with each other food, they don't hesitate to take a bite from my lunch box and neither I even when they are **pure vegetarian** (Don't even eat eggs).

Yes, that's right that we should have to be **careful** while eating meat offered from someone because the meat may be **haram** as @Mohammadhp says.

So maybe your friend actually doesn't know about Islam or maybe he has been given the wrong information.

Answer (score 1):

If the food offered is permitted to eat, It doesn't matter who is offering ,cooking or serving. The only reason, Muslims would avoid any offered food is that, there is a high chance of contamination which may change the food into not permitted food. If you let them know clearly what you are going to offer them in food, they would never reject the permitted food from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely true, although muslims generally do not eat **meat** or any kind of animal products offered by non muslims because the animal should be killed in a particular ceremony for its meat to be considered halal, meaning that you can eat it (i don't want to get into the details of the ceremony), otherwise consuming that meat is prohibited for muslims.